# Javascript Loop over array of objects and get unique values

Tags: javascript, loops, iteration

I have an array of car objects (carArray) and I want to loop over that array and fill a new array with the unique objects with only the type of **CarA**: 'Ford'.

```
const carArray = [
{carA:'Ford'},
{carA:'Ford'},
{carB:'GM'},
{carB:'GM'},
{carA:'Ford'},
{carA:'Ford'},
{carB:'GM'},
{carB:'Ford'},
]
```

Can someone tell me how I can do this?

Thank you so much for your time.
regards,
L

Comment: Do you only want one object that looks like `{carA:"Ford"}` or all Objects that look like  `{carA:"Ford"}` and have other unique properties, like  `{carA:"Ford", foo:"bar"}`?

Comment: Did you really mean to change the properties from `carA` and `carB`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick responses. I am only interested in let's say one object. {carA: "Ford"}, this value will be used in my front-end applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 let  newArray = [];
 carArray.forEach(function(car) {
   let arrayKey = Object.keys(car)[0]
   if (newArray.length > 0) {
       newArray.find(function (data) {
         if(!data.hasOwnProperty(Object.keys(data)[0])) { 
            newArray.push(car);
         }
       })
    }  else newArray.push(car)
 });
```

Comment: hello elraphty, thank you for the code snippet. I have a question, why do you check on the length of the newArray (if (newArray.length > 0) {)? The length of the array is now 128 long but I only have a few items in the array we iterate over.

Comment: If the array is of length 0 an error will be thrown because the array is empty

Comment: Only distinct object will be passed to the array, i.e if there is an Object with key Car A in the array, no other Object with Car A key will be pushed to the array because, it will be seen as a duplicate

Comment: sorry, another question, why do you use : let arrayKey = Object.keys(car)[0], it's not used in the function? If I want to have only the array filled with carB object, how do I do that?

Comment: My pleasure @Lino, if my code snippet was helpful, please upvote my answer or check if you feel is the correct answer

Comment: Object.keys[0] is the first key of the object so if only carB object u have to change theis condition `if(!data.hasOwnProperty(Object.keys(data)[0]))` to something like this `if(arrayKey === 'carB') { newArray.push(car) }`.  So u might not need this find `newArray.find(function (data){}) function anymore, since there can be duplicate carB,  remove the first if stament and just do this  `if(arrayKey === 'carB') { newArray.push(car) }`

Answer (score 3):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and use an array as neutral element for later getting the unique values.

```js
const
    array = [{ carA: 'Ford' }, { carA: 'Ford' }, { carB: 'GM' }, { carB: 'GM' }, { carA: 'Ford' }, { carA: 'Ford' }, { carB: 'GM' }, { carB: 'Ford' }]
    carA = [].concat(...new Set(array.map(({ carA = [] }) => carA)));
    
console.log(carA);
```

Comment: not sure what is up with OPs code, but ford is also in carB

Comment: @epascarello, i read the question for getting unique values from property `carA`.